# Unity2D C# Reloading progress bar not working propertly

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, progress-bar, unity3d-gui

[image: Reloading bar problem]

So I'm making a top-down tank shooter game and I want to make a better reloading system than it was before. So I came to the idea that I need some king of progress bar. I knew how to make it so I started doing it. The problem is that it doesn't work properly. As I show in the .gif above, the progress bar don't go down when you shoot second time. Because I'm new to unity, I still don't know everything very good. So I came here, maybe someone could help.

EDIT: 
I just found another problem and maybe an answer why I have this problem. The second time my script tries to reload, my "needTimer" bool is false, thus the progress bar is not going down when it's false. The new question would be why it becomes false instead of true?
My reloading script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Reload : MonoBehaviour {

    public float ammo;
    public Image progress;
    public bool alreadyReloading;
    public bool needTimer;

    void Start () {
        alreadyReloading = false;
    }
    IEnumerator needtimertime(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (6.5f);
        needTimer = false;
    }
    IEnumerator uztaisyt(){
        Debug.Log ("REEELOUUUDING!");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.5f);
        ammo += 1;
        alreadyReloading = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (needTimer == true) {
            timer ("");
        }
        if (ammo < 5) {
            if(alreadyReloading == false){
                needTimer = true;
                StartCoroutine(uztaisyt());
                alreadyReloading = true;
            }
        }
        if (progress.fillAmount <= 0) {
            progress.fillAmount = 1.0f; 
        }
    }

    void timer(string tipas){
        progress.fillAmount -=  Time.deltaTime / 6.5f;
        StartCoroutine (needtimertime ());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is value of ammo variable when you trying to shoot second time?

Comment: @Pawel Marecki  4 and goes down everytime you shoot. It is showed in the gif

Comment: Please clarify: _alreadyReloading_ and _needTimer_ are public, are they being called from any other object in the scene?  Also, where and how is the _ammo_ field being decremented?  If the timing of _ammo_ being decremented is out of sync with the Reload Update() function, that could be a possible culprit.

Comment: the both bools are not using in any other script, I set them to public for debugging purposes. You can remove public and nothing will change. Ammo is getting called in other script, called shooting, but only taking value, for easier calling. (like value1 = ...GetComponent....value2;).

Comment: Is there an initial value of _ammo_ that is being set in the Unity editor?

Comment: What does the 6.5 signify?

Comment: 6.5 is the amount of time in seconds to wait before the [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) return

Comment: That's clear. @Justasmig can you explain your reloading system?

Comment: my reloading system works like this: if ammo is below 5, it reloads one bullet every 6.5 seconds (I will change value for better gameplay), and only reloads one bullet, per time. Before there was system that reloaded after every shot, but I found that not being very good. I just didn't liked it how it work. So I decided to make this reload system. If something's not clear please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem and fixed it.
The problem was that *needTimer* was becoming false. So I found where and removed it.

my new code:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Reload : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float ammo;
public Image progress;
public bool alreadyReloading;
public bool needTimer;

void Start () {
    alreadyReloading = false;
    needTimer = false;
}

IEnumerator uztaisyt(){
    Debug.Log ("REEELOUUUDING!");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.5f);
    ammo += 1;
    alreadyReloading = false;
}

void Update () {
    if (ammo < 5.0f) {
        if(alreadyReloading == false){
            progress.fillAmount = 1.0f;
            needTimer = true;
            StartCoroutine(uztaisyt());
            alreadyReloading = true;
        }
        if (needTimer == true) {
            timer ("");
        }
    }
}

void timer(string tipas){
    progress.fillAmount -=  Time.deltaTime / 6.5f;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you start the *uztaisyt()* as a coroutine after shooting the first time (in the animation), *needTimer* is set to true and in the **next** *Update()* call, the *needtimertime()* coroutine will start.  Since both the *uztaisyt()* and *needtimertime()* have identical 6.5 second waits, they will **not** both return on the same frame update because *needtimertime()* will always be started in the next frame after *uztaisyt()*.  And, since there is no guarantee of the time interval between *Update()* calls, (see [Time and Frame Managment](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimeFrameManagement.html)), this interval may be more than expected and *needtimertime()* could return false in the frame right after *uztaisyt()* is called after firing the second time.

To ensure that the *needtimertime()* is always started (if not already running) immediately following a call for *uztaisyt()* (and called within the same frame update), you could try the following update to Reload script, (basically changes to the Update() method and when/how _isTimerRunning is set).

```
public class Reload : MonoBehaviour {

  public float ammo;
  public Image progress;

  private bool _alreadyReloading;
  private bool _isTimerRunning;

  void Start () {
      _alreadyReloading = false;
      _isTimerRunning = false;
  }

  IEnumerator needtimertime(){
      yield return new WaitForSeconds (6.5f);
      _needTimer = false;
  }

  IEnumerator uztaisyt(){
      Debug.Log ("REEELOUUUDING!");
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(6.5f);
      ammo += 1;
      _alreadyReloading = false;
  }

  void Update () {
      if (ammo < 5) {
          if(_alreadyReloading == false){                                        
              StartCoroutine(uztaisyt());
              _alreadyReloading = true;

              //this will check for and start the progress bar timer in the same udate call
              //so both coroutines finish on the same frame update
              if(!_isTimerRunning){
                _isTimerRunning = true;
                timer ("");
              }
          }
      }
      if (progress.fillAmount <= 0) {
          progress.fillAmount = 1.0f; 
      }
  }

  void timer(string tipas){
      progress.fillAmount -=  Time.deltaTime / 6.5f;
      StartCoroutine (needtimertime ());
  }
}
```

Comment: I found this method not working, because (I think, my opinion) the _timer()_ is called only once, not giving the progress bar enough time, to go down. (instead of going down it gets the value 0.9967943 and stops). What I think is that it need to be called like I was calling before ( if (needTimer == true) { timer (""); } ), but with this time method to synchronize the start time.